# Ошибка сегментирования, Ассемблерная вставка в язык СИ

Tags: ассемблер, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, сегментация

При компилировании выдает ошибку сегментирования:

```
#include <stdio.h> /*средства ввода-вывода для общения с человеком*/
#include <stdlib.h> /*базовые функции программ*/
#include <stdint.h> /*типы данных с гарантируемо известным занимаемым размером в памяти*/

int main(void)
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c=0;
    printf("a:");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("b:");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    asm //находим c = a+b
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix\n" /*Синтаксис Intel, допускается опускать % перед именами регистров*/
        "\n\tmovss   xmm0, [%1]" //Заносим данные в регистр
        "\n\tmovss   xmm1, [%2]" //Заносим данные в регистр
        "\n\taddss  xmm1, xmm0" //Складываем
        "\n\tmovss   [%0], xmm0"//Вывод данных из регистра
        : "=r"(c) //Возвращаемые данные
        : "r"(a), "r"(b) //Входные данные
        
    );
    
    printf("c = a+b = ");
    printf("%f\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: ошибка сегментирования]
[image: содержимое makefile]

Comment: Похоже, что Вы используете `Makefile` - покажите его содержимое

Comment: main.0: test.c
            gcc -masm=intel test.c
            ./a.out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откроем [первую попавшуюся](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmdsimd/MOVSS) справку по команде `MOVSS`. Там говорится:

> Команда **MOVSS** копирует младшее упакованное вещественное значение из операнда-источника (SIMD-регистр или операнд в памяти) в младшее 32-битное поле операнда-назначения (SIMD-регистр или операнд в памяти).

Как видим, её операндами могут быть только SIMD-регистры (но не регистры общего назначения) и ячейки памяти.

Что происходит в Вашем случае? Рассмотрим команду `movss xmm0, [%1]`. В итоговом [ассемблерном листинге](https://godbolt.org/z/3qdq1Yqnh) `%1` заменяется регистром общего назначения, в который перед этим попадает значение переменной `a`:

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]    // Копирование значения переменной a в EAX
...
movss   xmm0, [eax]    // Копирование из ячейки памяти с адресом, равным EAX
```

Как Вы уже догадались, в `EAX` находится заведомо непригодное значение для использования в качестве адреса, так как оно равно введённому с клавиатуры числу. Можно воспользоваться калькулятором для перевода `float` в шестнадцатеричный вид (например, [этим](https://gregstoll.com/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/)), чтобы лучше понять, к какому адресу производится обращение. В случае числа `1.0` таким значением будет `0x3f800000`, что вряд ли попадёт в диапазон выделенных программе операционной системой адресов – как итог, при попытке доступа к ячейке в неразрешённом диапазоне происходит аппаратное прерывание, и управление возвращается ядру операционной системы. Теоретически можно подобрать такое число, при котором программа не будет падать, но от этого она всё равно не станет правильно работать.

Какой из этого можно сделать вывод? Нужно передавать не само число, а указатель на него:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* Средства ввода-вывода для общения с человеком */
// #include <stdlib.h>  /* Базовые функции программ */
// #include <stdint.h>  /* Типы данных с гарантируемо известным занимаемым размером в памяти */

int main()
{
    float a, b, c;
    
    printf("a:");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    
    printf("b:");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    
    // Определяем и инициализируем указатели
    
    float *C = &c;    // %0, %1
    float *A = &a;    // %2
    float *B = &b;    // %3
    
    asm // Вычисляем c = a + b
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t"       // Синтаксис Intel, допускается опускать % перед именами регистров
        "movss   xmm0, [%2]     \n\t"       // Заносим данные в регистр
        "movss   xmm1, [%3]     \n\t"       // Заносим данные в регистр
        "addss   xmm1, xmm0     \n\t"       // Складываем
        "movss   [%0], xmm1     \n\t"       // Вывод данных из регистра
        : "=r"(C)                           // Возвращаемые данные (теперь это не число, а указатель на результат.
                                            // Впрочем, он нам не нужен - искомое число уже записано по этому адресу)
        : "r"(C), "r"(A), "r"(B)            // Входные данные
        : "%xmm0", "%xmm1"                  // Разрушаемые регистры
    );
    
    printf("c = a + b = %f\n", c);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Саму вставку можно немного упростить, сделав суммирование с операндом из памяти, при этом избежав лишнего копирования и сэкономив регистр:

```
    ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t"
    "movss   xmm0, [%2]     \n\t"    // Копируем значение по адресу A в XMM0
    "addss   xmm0, [%3]     \n\t"    // Суммируем непосредственно с ячейкой
    "movss   [%0], xmm0     \n\t"    // Копируем результат
    : "=r"(C)
    : "r"(C), "r"(A), "r"(B)
    : "%xmm0"
```

По использованию ассемблерных вставок в GCC есть [неплохое руководство](http://asmcourse.cs.msu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/gcc-inline-asm.pdf).

Comment: Cпасибо большое!